# Do you need to close a Connection of a JerseyClient (2.1.x) Response, if it has no body?

Tags: java, jersey, connection

In several cases we don't explicitly close the connections of a Response (made by JerseyClient), which leads to severe issues sometimes. On refactoring that I wondered, whether we need to call `close()` on a Response, which don't have a body.

---

I know so far:

- `response.close()` of course closes the Connection and is idempotent
- `respnse.readEntity()` closes it, too
- `response.getStatus()` does **not** close the connection

So, again, what is about *empty* Responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my eyes it is pretty obvious that it is better to always call `Response.close()` regardless of the entity content.

- There is no cost associated with the call
- It is a pretty counter-intuitive design to introduce a `Response.close()` method which does not needed to be called all times. This confusion creeps into your code.
- The Javadoc seems to say that it is not needed for empty entities but this is not quite clear.
- The JAX-RS implementation may misunderstand the [spec](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/) and require that `close()` is called.
- Your server implementation for a resource may change and now sends a entity. Then you have a resource leak on the client.
- You already mentioned that there seem to be problems...

Comment: Could you add a link to the spec? Thx!